# Show series of functions is uniformly convergent on $[a,\infty)$ for $a>0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I'd like to show that 
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x) $$
is uniformly convergent on $[a,\infty)$ for $a>0$ where
$$ f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+n^4x^2} $$

I have found that $f_n$ has a maximum of $\frac{1}{2n}$ on the interval $[0,\infty)$, specifically at $x=\frac{1}{n^2}$ (except for $f_0(x)=0$ for all $x$). Now this means
$$ f\bigg(\frac{1}{n^2}\bigg) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2n} \geq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{nx}{1+n^4x^2} \text{ for all }x\in[0,\infty) $$

I am unsure as to where to go from here.

Comment: YOU ARE NOT WORKING ON $[0, \infty )$, but on $[a, \infty)$. For fixed $a >0$, there exists some $N$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<a$ for $n>N$. For those $n$ the maximum of $f_n$ is attained at $a$ (since $f_n$ is decreasing on $[a, \infty)$!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You went in the right direction. Now, as Crostul wrote, you are asked to prove convergence only for $a>0$ so you should consider only the ranks $n\geqslant N$ where $N$ is such that: $a> \frac{1}{N^2}$ so that $f_n(a)$ is the maximum of $f_n$ on $[a,\infty)$.

Then, you are able to prove normal convergence for the  series $(\sum f_n)_{n\geqslant N}$ which is just $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} f_k(x)$ away from $(\sum f_n)_{n\geqslant 0}$ for $x\in [a,\infty)$ since, for $n\geqslant N$:

$$
||f_n||_\infty = f_n(a) = \frac{na}{1+n^4a^2} = O(\frac{1}{n^3})
$$

as $n\to \infty$.

Thus, $(\sum ||f_n||_\infty)_{n\geqslant N}$ converges since $(\sum \frac{1}{n^3})_{n\geqslant N}$ converges (Riemann series).

Normal convergence is established and it implies uniform convergence.

Comment: Thank you, I am comfortable with this, but why does convergence imply uniform convergence? Is it because we're considering the interval $[a,\infty)$?

Comment: Have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence#Distinctions) about normal convergence. There are many types of convergence as you might already know. Normal convergence being stronger than those that are usually studied (i.e., simple, absolute and uniform convergences). It does not depend on the interval. I hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use Calculus: use the inequality $2nx \leq n^{2}+x^{2}$. $$f_n(x) \leq \frac {n^{2}+x^{2}} {2(1+n^{4}x^{2})} \leq \frac {n^{2}+x^{2}} {2n^{4}x^{2}}=\frac 1 {2n^{2}a^{2}} +\frac 1 {2n^{4}}$$ and the series $\sum \frac 1 {2n^{2}a^{2}}$ and $\frac 1 {2n^{4}}$ both converge.